# Vuetify: fit v-image within the screen size

Tags: css, vue.js

My vue page have a photo gallery, and when a photo is selected, the dialog will jump out by setting the `selectedCard`.
While the image is not fitting the size of the screen.
I tried to set css with max height or width with 100% anywhere I can, but none of them are working.
How can I fix my css so that the whole image can be view on the screen without scrolling?
Screen cap: only half of the image can be shown
[image: only half of the image can be shown]

```
//Dialog component    
<template>
  <v-dialog :value="selectedCard" scrollable fullscreen hide-overlay>
    <v-card v-if="selectedCard">
      <v-container grid-list-sm fluid>
        <v-layout align-space-around row fill-height>
          <v-flex id="mainCardPanel">
            <v-layout align-space-around column fill-height>
              <v-flex xs12>
                <MyCard class="mainCard" :card="selectedCard"></MyCard>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs12>
                <v-btn> SomeButton </v-btn>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
// MyCard component
<template>
  <v-card flat tile class="d-flex justify-center" >
    <v-img :contain="true" :src=card.imageUrlHiRes
        :lazy-src=card.imageUrl class="grey lighten-2 Card">
      <template v-slot:placeholder>
        <v-layout fill-height align-center justify-center ma-0>
          <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="grey lighten-5"></v-progress-circular>
        </v-layout>
      </template>
    </v-img>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Share your working code here [https://codesandbox.io/s/vue](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)

Comment: Please share your CSS code as well or its almost impossible to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try using vh for your image height.
Perhaps this may work:

```
img {
  height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Added and its look better, but the image is still a little bit (around 10% of the image) larger than the screen. Still need to scroll in order to view the whole image

Comment: Try adjusting it to 80vh instead of 100vh

Answer (score 1):

add css width and hieght to 100%

```
img { 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    }
```

Comment: added but no effect on the image, still looks same as my screen cap

Comment: try this too add 'contain' in your tag too <v-img src="https://picsum.photos/510/300?random" aspect-ratio="1.7" contain></v-img>

Comment: i thing vuetify does't have class prop too check it in vuetify js website  too.then important note ,i noticed that vuetify does not use <img> ,it use div for displaying the image<div style="background-image:url()">

Comment: so i think this is main reason for your problem.if you noticed you can easily resolve this man

Answer (score 1):

If you want to appear full image use `:cover="true"` in `<v-img>`.
If you you want to appear the whole image, you can put follow CSS.

```
.v-image__image{
 background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

This is not recommended way.Because image's ratio will be wrong.

Comment: added the cover but is not working well, the image still showing the same. And I need to keep the ratio of image

Comment: May you put some code in Codepen or something about this case? I have to check css and figure out this issue.

Comment: `:cover` isn't a valid Vuetify property on `v-img`. It should be `:contain` and that's already in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure HTML appears to even be simpler and better for me. The vuetify just complicate simple things sometimes. Use `v-col`, `div`, any block...

```
<v-row class="fill-height" 
    justify="center" 
    align="center" 
    style="background-image: url('card.imageUrlHiRes'); 
    background-size: cover;" >
          
  </v-row>
```